# How to pull all new tags using libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I would like to use libgit2sharp to achieve `git pull --tags`.
If I try to do a pull like this:

```
repo.Network.Pull(new Signature("name", "my@email.com", new DateTimeOffset()), new PullOptions());
```

then I get the new commits but not the new tags which are pointing to these commits.
I tried to use `PullOptions` to modify the behaviour like this:

```
var sig = new Signature("name", "my@email.com", new DateTimeOffset());
var opts = new PullOptions{ FetchOptions = new FetchOptions {TagFetchMode = TagFetchMode.All} };
repo.Network.Pull(sig, opts);
```

This throws the following exception:

```
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' doesn't match the destination
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.ZeroResult(Int32 result)
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_remote_fetch(RemoteSafeHandle remote, Signature signature, String logMessage)
  at LibGit2Sharp.Network.DoFetch(RemoteSafeHandle remoteHandle, FetchOptions options, Signature signature, String logMessage)
  at LibGit2Sharp.Network.Fetch(Remote remote, FetchOptions options, Signature signature, String logMessage)
  at LibGit2Sharp.Network.Pull(Signature merger, PullOptions options)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Aside from the answer below, the exception that is thrown isn't very explicit. Would you mind opening an issue in the **[tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues)** with a complete repro case against a publicly accessible repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stangely, I can't find any `--tags` option in the latest official git **[documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)**.

However, in LibGit2Sharp you can perform the equivalent `git fetch --all` using the following code (or one of the other `.Fetch()` overloads):

```
repo.Network.Fetch(remote, new FetchOptions { TagFetchMode = TagFetchMode.All });
```

### Update

The current tip of LibGit2Sharp `vNext` branch doesn't cringe with this code. However, as seen in the **[issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/927)** you've raised, version v0.20.x does indeed throws.

**v0.21** will fix this issue.

Comment: git-pull will pass any extra arguments to git-fetch.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is now very much obsolete!

`repo.Network.Fetch` now takes a `IEnumerable<string> refspecs`

Comment: This looks like it should be a comment on the answer, not an answer by itself.  How does your answer solve the initial problem?  Can you expound on this and provide a full solution?

Comment: I can’t add comments to other answers yet…so troll me I don’t care